# Mysql Select record where in caluse

Tags: mysql

I have following table

User

- UserId
- LocationId

Location

- UserId
- LocationId
- CityId

Both table contain some other fields. I have following query

```
SELECT * FROM users where LocationId in (Select LocationId from locations where UserId = 118);
```

this query returns me no of record which is present in `users` table where locationid present in location table. What I want If there is no any record found by this query `Select LocationId from locations where UserId = 118` at that time I want to show all **records** from **users** table. Right now it is returning 0 record if there is no any location.

Comment: I am afraid conditional select is only possible using stored procedure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query

```
select * from users u left join locations l on u.LocationId = l.LocationId and  u.UserId = 118
```

It will return all records from Users eventhough no matching records found from user table with UserID = 118

Comment: Thanks. Actually I tried this query before posting the question. But it wasn't returned anything. But now it's working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

With the requirement stated in to the question

> What I want If there is no any record found by this query Select
>   LocationId from locations where UserId = 118 at that time I want to
>   show all records from users table

You can use `left join` with an additional joining condition as `location.UserId=118` But in this case it will also return non-matching record or in other words the complete user table.

So having the conditons
- if userid is found in location table then only return that user data
- else all the user data

The best approach would be to create a stored procedure as

```
delimiter //
create procedure find_user_location_based(in user_id int)
begin
   if (select 1 from locations where UserId = user_id ) then
    begin
      SELECT * FROM users where  UserId = user_id ;
    end;
   else
     begin
      SELECT * FROM users;
     end;
   end if;
end;//

delimiter ;
```

Then pass the user id into the procedure as

```
call find_user_location_based(118);
```

Answer (score -1):

When You are Using  `SELECT * FROM users where LocationId in (Select LocationId from locations where UserId = 118)` it working as a `inner join` 
thats why it's returning 0 records for not matching the record in both table.

and you want to return record from atleast one table so you have to use LEFT/RIGHT Join

> try Left Join like this

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u  left join locations l on 
u.LocationId=l.LocationId and l.UserId=118
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried but it is returning 0 record. I am using `MySQL` db